# Print Search results to Web page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a search on a local PC log file. The function below works fine if I run it from the CLI of my local pc. Basically the function does a search on all files in a directory. If a line in one of the files has the word "bee" in it, then that line will be printed out.

What im trying to do is run the script and print out every line that has the word "bee" to the index.html file page. I would imagine the below would work, but I guess im missing something. Advice is welcomed.

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

### views.py

```
import re
import os

def index(request):
    log_location = "C:\\folder1"

    for dirpath, dirnames, log_file in os.walk(log_location):
        for file in log_file:
            file = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
            with open(file) as open_directory:
                for line in open_directory:
                    if 'bee' in line:
                        context =  line
                        print(line)

    return render(request, 'testapp/index.html', context)
```

### index.html

```
<html></html>
<h1>{{line}}</h1>
</html>
```

Comment: `context` is supposed to be a dictionary like `{'line': 'some text'}`, but you're setting it to the line itself. The template is trying to access `context['line']` but cannot find it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to build a list.

```
def index(request):
    log_location = "C:\\folder1"

    lines = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, log_file in os.walk(log_location):
        for file in log_file:
            file = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
            with open(file) as open_directory:
                for line in open_directory:
                    if 'bee' in line:
                        lines.append(line)
```

And you need to pass a dictionary to the renderer

```
rendered_data = {'line': r'\n'.join(lines) }
return render(request, 'testapp/index.html', rendered_data )
```